# Updating a byte[] in Android Sqlite Database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have successfully added a blob file into my database. but when i try to update it gives errors. I tried two methods here is my code.I searched but everywhere i found adding in database not updating a byte[].

1- First i tried to save simple pro byte[]. but it said it didn't recognize the value of byte[].

2- Then i tried Arrays.toString(pro) but no such column.

```
      public void profile(String status,byte[] pro, SQLiteDatabase db){
    ContentValues sv = new ContentValues();
    sv.put(mDatabase.Tableinfo.status, status);
    sv.put(mDatabase.Tableinfo.Pic, pro) ;
    db.update(mDatabase.Tableinfo.Table_Name, sv, mDatabase.Tableinfo.status + "=" + status + " and " + mDatabase.Tableinfo.Pic + "=" + Arrays.toString(pro), null);
   // db.insert(mDatabase.Tableinfo.Table_Name, null, sv);

   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "and": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE User SET status=?,Pro_pic=? WHERE status= and Pro_pic=[-119, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82, 0, 0, 0, 120, 0, 0, 0, 1............ and to infinite .
```

You would probably suggest this but I even tried this but can't add a byte[] into String array.

```
  mDatabase.Tableinfo.status + "=? and " +mDatabase.Tableinfo.Pic +"=?", new String[]{status,pro(this is a byte array)}, null);
```

Comment: Dont put status and pro in the where clause. Maybe an _ID?

Comment: I don't have any idea i tried but couldn't get it right, i can't add a byte[] into String[]. In this table there is only one row so no ID that's why i don't wanna insert. i wanna update it. Check my question.

Comment: If theres only one row you can update all rows. db.update(mDatabase.Tableinfo.Table_Name, sv, null, null);

Comment: but there are other columns. Will it work?

Comment: Id say columns not specified in contentvalues will not be affected. Verify.

Comment: Its working Thanks dude.

Answer (score 1):

Add single quotation marks may works

```
db.update(mDatabase.Tableinfo.Table_Name, sv, mDatabase.Tableinfo.status  "="    
    + status + " and " + mDatabase.Tableinfo.Pic + "= '"+Arrays.toString(pro)+"'", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Note - I have only one row So just doing this solved my problem. No selection no other things.

```
     db.update(mDatabase.Tableinfo.Table_Name, sv,null, null);
```